# Use Page Width when printing NSTableView instead of the view width

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, printing, macos-sierra

This seems like it should be simple...

I have a basic NSTableView in a window. The window is arbitrarily resizable (width + height).  The tableview is pinned to the edges of the window and it has a single column that contains view-based table rows.  The table rows have content pinned to the left and right edges of the cells, so as you resize the width of the window, you are effectively adjusting how much white space is in the middle of the cell.

I'm now trying to implement printing for this tableview.  When I set up the `NSPrintOperation`, I'm passing my tableview subclass as the view to print.   My desired result is this:  I want the width of the tableview to be resized to the width of the page (regardless of how wide the window is right now on screen).  I don't want to adjust the scaling factor (because that affects width + height) - I simply want the result to be as if I manually resized my window to exactly match the width of a printed page and then hit "print".

I've tried setting `horizontalPagination` to `.fitPagination` - but the problem there is that seems to apply a scaling factor to the width + height (which means if the window is currently "very wide", it makes the row height really small as it compensates for the width).

I've tried overriding `adjustPageWidthNew:left:right:limit:` in my tableview subclass - but that never gets called.

I suppose I could create a duplicate tableview and re-set it up exactly like the one I have on screen, but that feels like overkill when the view I want is already good to go - I just need to temporarily resize the width while I'm printing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `print:` prints the view as is. It's much easier to use an extra invisible view for printing.

Comment: yeah - I'm currently going down the road of duplicating my tableview to make a print-specific view.  It just feels like a heavy handed approach since the on-screen tableview is exactly how I want it to look...it just needs the width to be sized appropriately.